# Jersey client throw ConcurrentModificationException when sending multiple async calls

Tags: asynchronous, callback, jersey, grizzly

I am trying the Asynchronous Client-side and Server-side Callbacks sample from Jersey document(https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10146).

I am using Grizzle client connector and server factory. The difference from the sample is I sent 10000 requests by for loop. And I set a clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.ASYNC_THREADPOOL_SIZE, 20);

Then client throws below exception:

```html
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.processFailure(ClientRuntime.java:227)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$null$3(ClientRuntime.java:185)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$$Lambda$103/1511834685.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:312)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$createRunnableForAsyncProcessing$4(ClientRuntime.java:159)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$$Lambda$100/1987360300.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
 at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Views$1$1.next(Views.java:96)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils.asHeaderString(HeaderUtils.java:230)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils.lambda$asStringHeadersSingleValue$2(HeaderUtils.java:202)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils$$Lambda$108/1341461635.apply(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$209(Collectors.java:1321)
 at java.util.stream.Collectors$$Lambda$21/936580213.accept(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
 at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
 at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils.asStringHeadersSingleValue(HeaderUtils.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector.writeOutBoundHeaders(GrizzlyConnector.java:490)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector.apply(GrizzlyConnector.java:268)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$null$3(ClientRuntime.java:183)
 ... 14 more
```

And I found many sockets are open by using netstat. It looks every request will open a socket. So after a little time, another exception will throw as below:

```html
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Too many open files
 at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector$2.onThrowable(GrizzlyConnector.java:318)
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyResponseFuture.failed(GrizzlyResponseFuture.java:159)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:187)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:277)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerSetException(SafeFutureImpl.java:382)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.failure(SafeFutureImpl.java:122)
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyResponseFuture.abort(GrizzlyResponseFuture.java:72)
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$1.failed(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:138)
Invocation failed.
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Futures.notifyFailure(Futures.java:129)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.notifyAsyncPollersOfFailure(SingleEndpointPool.java:1182)
null
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.access$1500(SingleEndpointPool.java:102)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.onFailedToConnect(SingleEndpointPool.java:1321)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool$ConnectCompletionHandler.failed(SingleEndpointPool.java:1290)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.ReadyFutureImpl.addCompletionHandler(ReadyFutureImpl.java:147)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.connect(SingleEndpointPool.java:1157)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.SingleEndpointPool.take(SingleEndpointPool.java:788)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.connectionpool.MultiEndpointPool.take(MultiEndpointPool.java:592)
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.ConnectionManager.openAsync(ConnectionManager.java:143)
 at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:174)
 at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient.executeRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:506)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly.connector.GrizzlyConnector.apply(GrizzlyConnector.java:274)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$null$3(ClientRuntime.java:183)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$$Lambda$103/694396298.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:312)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.lambda$createRunnableForAsyncProcessing$4(ClientRuntime.java:159)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$$Lambda$100/1987360300.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I didn't change the max open file number in my system. I think even I changes the number to a high value it still will be used out when sending sufficient requests. Its not the root cause.

The questions come up to my mind are:

1, Why the ConcurrentModificationException throws?

2, How to limit the connection number opened by Grizzle and can be integrated with Jersey? It might help to get rid of above exceptions.

The client code:

```html
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.connectorProvider(new GrizzlyConnectorProvider());

    clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.ASYNC_THREADPOOL_SIZE, 20);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

    client.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
    WebTarget target = client.target(serverURI);
    AsyncInvoker asyncInvoker = target.request().async();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

      Future<Response> responseFuture = asyncInvoker.post(
          Entity.entity(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),
          new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Response response) {

              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              MyResponse res = response.readEntity(MyResponse.class);
              String result;
              try {
                result = mapper.writeValueAsString(res);
                System.out.println(result);
              } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
              System.out.println("Invocation failed.");
              throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
          });
    }
```

Sever code:

```html
  @POST
  @Path("testAsyncCallback")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void handleEventReport(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
      JaxbBean o, @Context Request req) {
    asyncResponse.register(new CompletionCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(Throwable throwable) {

      }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        MyResponse result = veryExpensiveOperation();
        asyncResponse.resume(result);
      }

      private MyResponse veryExpensiveOperation() {
        // ... very expensive operation

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
          String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(o);
          System.out.println(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        response.setResult(1);
        return response;
      }
    }).start();

  }
```

Thanks in advance.